# Script don't work in woocommerce "place order" section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I put custom button in the place order section, in the file `review-order.php`.
I want to run a script that makes things happen when the button is clicked, but the script in that area does't work.
And also the button is running twice, once when the page is load, and once after ajax finish to load.
In any other part in the page, the script does work.

The code where I put the button:

```
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <tfoot>
    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
        <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
            <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && 'excl' === WC()->cart->tax_display_cart ) : ?>
        <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <tr class="tax-total">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

    <tr class="order-total">
        <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    <a id="test-btn">test</a>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#shipping_method input').change(function(){
        if($('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup5').is(':checked')){
            $('#billing_address_1_field, #billing_address_2_field, #billing_address_3_field, #billing_city_field, #billing_note_field').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
    $('#test-btn').click(function(){
        alert('test');

    });

});
```

I enqueue this file in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sukot_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
function sukot_wp_enqueue_scripts(){

    if( is_checkout() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('checkout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/checkout.js', array('jquery'), time() );
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: So your problem is the alert('test') code is not firing? I'm not used to woocommerce, but maybe use $('body').on('click' , '#test-button' , function(){}) solves your issue, if some woocommerce module is pushing that html from AJAX -which seems is the case from what you say at the starting of your Q-

Comment: The checkout is now loaded via ajax, so `#test-btn` is probably not in the dom on page load.

Comment: @helgatheviking So how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

As Sergeon suggested, you can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$( ".shop_table" ).on( "click", "#test-btn", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

If that doesn't work then you may need to "bubble" up the chain a little higher than `.shop_table` and I would try the next closest container `div`.